# MuleSoft Anypoint advice

Tags: anypoint-studio, pentaho-data-integration, data-integrity, mulesoft

My organization is looking to install MuleSoft to support data and process integration. We have 5 ERP's and need to consolidate data quickly for analysis and process improvements. Looking for references or issues you have experience with MuleSoft.

Comment: Since your question is very generic, I would say Mule being an ESB should be able to connect your ERP's with other systems with less effort as compared to non-ESB products. Do you use any existing ESB in your enterprise ?

Comment: Your question is too open ended and include too few details. You could mention  which ERPs are you trying to connect.

Comment: Agreeing to what earlier commentators mentioned about being generic and lack of information, I am wondering if there can be architecture and consulting level help that can be rendered over this platform.

Answer (score 0):

While seeking extra details from this curious person, I have got an interesting research paper putting up light on Enterprise Integration Architecture while leveraging the tools of Middleware like Oracle SOA Fusion Middleware and MuleSoft ESB specifically. There are many other tools that are fairly doing well in the market and yes are available as open source and at fairly high price in terms of yearly licencing cost. Coming back to main point. You get what you ask for!

Answer (score 0):

First, Kindly go through the relevant MuleSoft Documentation to get started. Perform few POC's and observe how user friendly the tool is ! The tool is not too generic to quote and unquote standard inherent issue. It's the developer's ability which makes the tool to be used efficiently.
When you talk about Middleware Integration Services, you should have a background story of all the tools which falls under such category. Have you explored the other options ! such as spring boot micro services, dell boomi, web methods before.